# IBM Cloud Functions: How to create secured web action using Terraform

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions, terraform-provider-ibm

I am able to [create a new IBM Cloud Functions action using the Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/function_action).

```
resource "ibm_function_action" "sendEmail" {
  name      = "${ibm_function_package.cloudmailer.name}/sendEmail"
  namespace = ibm_function_namespace.namespace.name

  exec {
    kind = "nodejs:12"
    code = file("smtp_email.js")
  }
  publish = true
  user_defined_parameters = var.server_config
}
```

How can I turn the above action into a [web action](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-actions_web)? How can I specify the configuration for its password protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [annotations argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/function_action#user_defined_annotations). It holds key / value pairs of these [documented action annotations](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-annotations).

```
resource "ibm_function_action" "sendEmail" {
  name      = "${ibm_function_package.cloudmailer.name}/sendEmail"
  namespace = ibm_function_namespace.namespace.name

  exec {
    kind = "nodejs:12"
    code = file("smtp_email.js")
  }
  publish = true
  user_defined_parameters = var.server_config
  user_defined_annotations =  <<EOF
    [
      {
        "key": "web-export",
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "key": "require-whisk-auth",
        "value": "your-web-secret"
      }
    ]
EOF

}
```

The above **web-export** turns the action into a web action, **require-whisk-auth** enables authentication for security and its value sets the password. I have turned it into a [working sample](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/cloudmailer/blob/main/tf/main.tf).